# Canvas image object is not moving with style.left

Tags: javascript, animation, html5-canvas

Recently i am trying to animate or say move a object using javascript and HTML5: but i am stuck , can anybody tell me what's wrong with my code:

javascript code (whats wrong in this code below):

---

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('my-first');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(imageObj,0,0,360,240);
                             };

imageObj.src = 'img/bakshi.jpg';
imageObj.style.position= 'relative'; 
imageObj.style.left = '0px'; 

function moveRight(){
    imageObj.style.left = parseInt(imageObj.style.left)+10+'px';
                };
```

---

HTML5 code:

**
    
    
    
          "My experimentation"

```
<canvas id="my-first" width="360" height="240">
 your browser doesn't support canvas
</canvas>

<script src="file.js"></script> 
<audio src="i_am_bakshi.mp3" controls autoplay> </audio>
<input type="button" value="Click Me" onclick="moveRight();" /> 
</body>
</html>
```

**

Comment: are you sure `moveRight()` is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is that your image is not a DOM object and you are trying to move it with DOM style. Instead you must recall drawImage() with updated coordinates.

```
var X = 0
function moveRight(){
  X += 10;
  context.drawImage(imageObj,X,0,360,240);
}
```

Comment: This code only changes the *width* of the image, X needs to be the second argument (`context.drawImage(imageObj, X, 0)`). 4. and 5. are width and height (not really needed if no scaling is wanted).

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't move the image using the styles, in fact, you're drawing it into canvas.

You should draw it to another position:

```
context.drawImage(imageObj,parseInt(imageObj.style.left)+10,0,360,240);
```